# 2D map render in opengl

Tags: opengl

I use some small chip picture to make up a map.
When it's static, it's all ok.But when I use the glTranslated to move it.
It always has some small shiver.

I use this to init

```
glEnable(GL_FLAT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER , 0.5);
```

I use this in display function.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(-_viewpos.x, _viewpos.y, 0);
if(_displayFunc)
{
  _displayFunc(this, time0);
}
glPopMatrix();
```

and this to render a picture

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0);glVertex2d(p1.x, p1.y);
glTexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0);glVertex2d(p2.x, p2.y);
glTexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0);glVertex2d(p3.x, p3.y);
glTexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0);glVertex2d(p4.x, p4.y);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnd();
```

I think the problem maybe is that when i change the coordinate  from int to double,
It may have a pixel offset?
 How to solve it?

Comment: Could you please provide your projection matrix code as well, as an screenshot of the shiver? Probably it's an glTexParameter GL_NEAREST/GL_LINEAR issue (depending what exactly you meant with 'small shiver')

Comment: Either that or a problem with floating point precision.  glTranslated often just truncates to float under the hood I think.